# Hibernate ORM T-SQL Queries causing Deadlocks in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, orm

I have a SQL Server 2016 database and we have been using the Hibernate Java (ORM) as Front End to access the database.

The below scenario is causing the deadlock: one of the Transaction is doing the select operations involving many tables in joins as below:

```
select * 
from table 1 
inner join table2_ on table1PK = table2FK 
left outer join table3 on table1PK = table3FK 
left outer join table4_ on table4FK = table3PK 
... 
where Table1PK = '1234' and table3.Status <> 'NA'
```

Another transaction is doing the `UPDATE` on any of the table involved in the above joins

```
Update Table4 
set columnA = 'XYZ' 
where Table4PK = 'ABC'
```

Frequently getting the deadlocks between this 2 Transactions.

Below were the analysis gathered:

1. All the tables involved in the `Select` statement joins are on the PK FK relationship
2. All PK & FK Columns have indexes (PK clustered & FK nonclustered)
3. Since the queries are generated from the ORM Hibernate hence it retrieves all the columns in the `Select` statement
4. Execution Plan does a nonclustered index seek followed by the Key Lookup for all the tables
5. Select statement used the Shared S locks and Update statements are using the Exclusive X locks
6. Page Level Locks are disabled for the above tables
7. Statistics and Indexes are up to date / Frequently updated

Can't use the READ Committed Snapshot and Read Uncommitted isolation Levels due to the Application Logic.

Any suggestions to avoid the deadlocks for the above scenario.

Deadlock Trace:

```
    <deadlock>
     <victim-list>
      <victimProcess id="process2ba81fa8c8" />
     </victim-list>
     <process-list>
      <process id="process2ba81fa8c8" taskpriority="0" logused="0"                     
    waitresource="KEY: 7:72057597045899264 (5a800aed3519)" waittime="2537" ownerId="1798795" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2019-12-12T13:17:02.820" XDES="0x2841883a40" lockMode="S" schedulerid="6" kpid="10140" status="suspended" spid="429" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2019-12-12T13:17:02.823" lastbatchcompleted="2019-12-12T13:17:02.820" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.820" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="" hostpid="0" loginname="" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1798795" currentdb="" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
         <executionStack>
          <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="24" stmtend="33928" sqlhandle="0x02000000a700b227b6df842918a30ca7f4b4cd5ff967f9810000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
      unknown    </frame>
          <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
      unknown    </frame>
         </executionStack>
         <inputbuf>
(@P0 bigint)select ... from ABC inner join XYZ  </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process2ba81f8108" taskpriority="0" logused="5812788" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057596983508992 (c750150781e8)" waittime="2306" ownerId="1795488" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-12-12T13:17:02.180" XDES="0x2bb290d478" lockMode="X" schedulerid="5" kpid="9876" status="suspended" spid="382" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2019-12-12T13:17:03.053" lastbatchcompleted="2019-12-12T13:17:03.053" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.053" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="" hostpid="0" loginname="" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1795488" currentdb="" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
         <executionStack>
          <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="1462" stmtend="3664" sqlhandle="0x020000007bd3bd2f098d8e394643ad11df2b1027b5b67fde0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
         </executionStack>
               <inputbuf>(@P0 bigint,@P1 datetime2,@P2 datetime2,@P3 varchar(8000),@P4 varchar(8000),@P5 datetime2,)update [dbo].[XYZ] set []=@P0, []=@P1, []=@P2, []=@P3, []=@P4,</inputbuf>
              </process>
             </process-list>
             <resource-list>
        <keylock hobtid="72057597045899264" dbid="7" objectname="DB.dbo.ABC" indexname="IX_ABC_XYZFK" id="lock2afc8ca500" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057597045899264">
         <owner-list>
          <owner id="process2ba81f8108" mode="X" />
         </owner-list>
         <waiter-list>
          <waiter id="process2ba81fa8c8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
         </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057596983508992" dbid="7" objectname="DB.dbo.XYZ" indexname="PK_XYZ" id="lock2afd023080" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057596983508992">
         <owner-list>
          <owner id="process2ba81fa8c8" mode="S" />
         </owner-list>
         <waiter-list>
          <waiter id="process2ba81f8108" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
         </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
       </resource-list>
      </deadlock>
```

Comment: Post your deadlock graph as that explains exactly what resources are deadlocking.

Comment: Hi Dale, The deadlock is happening on the Key level as Page level locks are disabled. The keys Involved are the PK & FK from the tables

Comment: Post your deadlock graph :)

Comment: And the expertise in this area is higher on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Deadlock graph attached in the original post

Comment: Clarify what columns the UPDATE is modifying, and whether you have any foreign keys with CASCADE UPDATE.  And whether the UPDATING transaction has made any previous updates in the same transaction.  It's not clear why the UPDATEing process owns an X lock on an index of table ABC.

Comment: @JeetendraPardeshi As David says above, from the update statement you have posted, there is no reason that the update process would need an exclusive lock on table `ABC` *BEFORE* attempting to acquire an exclusive lock on table `XYZ` (the table being updated). So there is something more going on here.

Comment: @David...We don't have any cascading UPDATE for any of the PK-FK Relationship....Only problem is the TSQL Queries are getting generated from the Hibernatethat Includes Multiple Tables joins and if any of those tables happens to be UPDATED the SELECT becomes the deadlock victim.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your tables are not actually called ABC and XYZ. Taking obfuscation aside, I would review where you are mentioning : `WHERE Table4PK = 'ABC'`

Doublecheck that your data types line up. If, for example your PK is numeric and your WHERE clause passing a string, SQL may sometimes scan data more than it needs to.

The deadlocks will occur in deadlock situtations, when data is attempting to read while data is attempting to write to the same place. You mention that your application logic will not allow you to Read Uncomitted. Can you update your application logic to silently retry selects in the event of a deadlock error?

Also, you will want to review disk performance for IO bottlenecks. If data can move faster, then it will be less likely to contend. If you are hitting a write bottleneck, you could consider moving your indexes to a different filegroup and disk if possible, for example.

Comment: Hi Sean, I have double checked that the PK and FK Data Type both are Numeric and where Clause is also passing a numeric value. Most of my NC Indexes are doing a Index Seek Operation plus Key lookup (as getting all columns from Tables due to Hibernate).

Comment: Please clarify what do yo mean by "Can you update your application logic to silently retry selects in the event of a deadlock error?"

Comment: So you are looking at it from a data administration standpoint: How to get rid of deadlocks. 

But the overall symptom is that somewhere application code is attempting to read data using ORM code and getting a deadlock error back from the database? 

What happens when that application receives a deadlock error, does it then turn this into an exception or error? 

I wonder if the code, upon receiving a database deadlock error, can be updated to attempt to retry the select/read operation, after the first attempt was chosen as the deadlock victim. This would make it seem like just a delay.